# java class is not accessible through another class within the same package

Tags: java, import, package

Can anyone tell me why the below code is not working,

First file is,

```
   package pack;
import pack.*;
public class please
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        plz p=new plz(1);
    }
}
```

Second file is,

```
package pack;
public class plz
{
    public plz(int i)
    {

    }
}
```

But when i compile please.java then the error says that it cannot find 'plz()'
Kindly guide me through.

Comment: This line is redundant in the first class: `import pack.*;`.

Comment: Please post the exact error message you get - the error message you've paraphrased doesn't correspond with your code sample.

Comment: What does your compile command look like.  Have you included the classpath?

Comment: Are the files in the same folder?

Comment: Are you compiling via the command line?

Comment: Please read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm)

Comment: **you dont have to import pack.***

Comment: @jpmc26 yeah they are in the same folder

Comment: @DuncanJones well actually i'm running this in a command prompt, the exception is quite large and i m unable to copy-paste it, but the main exception says "noclassdeffounderror"

Comment: @SaumilSoni Why can't you copy/paste it? Even a screen-shot would help, but copy/paste is functionality that is available in every terminal I've ever used.

Comment: @DuncanJones c:\My programs\Java\Advance java\pack>javac please.java
please.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                plz p=new plz(1);
                ^
  symbol:   class plz
  location: class please
please.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
                plz p=new plz(1);
                          ^
  symbol:   class plz
  location: class please
2 errors

Comment: @DuncanJones sorry about the format

Answer (score 3):

When you're compiling, you will either need to:

- Compile both source files at the same time; or
- Provide a classpath for the second call to `javac`, which includes the class generated in the first call.

Your error message likely means that you are not doing either of these, and so `javac` cannot see the definition of the `plz` class when compiling `please`.

Answer (score 0):

use first class as

```
package pack;

public class please
{
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        plz p=new plz(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you describe how this is different from the OP's code? I see you removed the unnecessary import. Is that it?

Comment: @Kevin Bowersox `import pack.*;` is redundant in the please class.

Comment: @vijay ramani the file compile now but produces exception of required class not found

Comment: @Saumil Soni have you put both class in same package..?

Comment: @VijayRamani yeah both the class are in the same package

Comment: @Saumil Soni have used any IDE for running this ?

Comment: @VijayRamani nope i m trying to run this on command prompt without any ide

Comment: I down-voted - this doesn't appear to be a solution. (As per @KevinBowersox's comment).

Answer (score 0):

if it really says that it can not find plz() it is true because your method takes a parameter.possible in please class you call plz's method without a parameter.i mean it is not issue of package issue.it  is about method issue.and you dont have to import pack.*

Comment: `public plz(int i) `is constructor not a method so it must be call with 

` plz p=new plz(1);`

Solution is :
 you dont have to import pack.*

Comment: ok you are right.i am correcting it:compiler does not say that it can not see the second class.it says that it can not find the constructor without parameter.

Comment: @ankit337 No, that's not the solution.